# Problem with bib2gls

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

In the "The glossaries package v4.46: a guide for beginner" on page 24 (from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) it is stated:

Having the file myDoc.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources % input file created by bib2gls
[% instructions to bib2gls:
src={entries}, % terms defined in entries.bib
sort={en-GB}% sort according to this locale
]
\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
description={an example}}
\begin{document}
A \gls{sample}.
\printunsrtglossaries % iterate over all defined entries
\end{document}
```

and entries.bib:

```
@entry{sample,
name = {sample},
description = {an example}
}
```

and running

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

would result in a correct pdf file, but during the step:

```
bib2gls myDoc
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/dickimawbooks/bib2gls/Bib2Gls : Unsupported major.minor versi
on 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

So either I must do wrong or the instructions are incorrect, but what ?

Comment: Your `entries.bib` looks bad. The field `description` needs an actual description as in `description = {an example}`. The @entry starts with `{` but after the corrected description field needs `}` to close the entry. After doing such corrections it worked fine in my computer

Comment: @LuisTurcio thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately it was just a copy / paste error to the question, in my original file the contents is (in my opinion) correct. Please see the updated question.

Comment: This seems like a Java version error, you need Java 1.8 or higher. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0.

Comment: @marijn Thanks might be the right call, I have 1.7.0_67 so it looks like I have to upgrade to a newer version, I have to see what I can do...

Comment: I installed the 1.8 version and it looks like this is solving the problem. @marijn maybe worth an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bib2gls` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/bib2gls.pdf) mentions the following on the first page:

> Note that bib2gls is a Java application, and requires at least Java
> 8<sup>1</sup>.
>
> [...]
>
> <sup>1</sup> The List.sort method used to sort the entries was only
> introduced to Java 8.

The error message `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` is a check that the Java interpreter performs to see if the version set as a target during compilation (here `52.0`) is compatible with the currently installed version of Java. 52 is Java 8 (also known as Java 1.8).

So the solution to this problem is to update the Java runtimes. See for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0.